# Overriding body background with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

`$('body').css('background-color', 'blue');` does not work for me.

There seems to be other matched CSS rules that prevail on the page.

Is there a way I can force this CSS to work? This also doesn't work when I try background-image...

With Google Chrome's CSS explorer there are three different matched CSS rules for body.

I don't understand how this works and why this above JQuery isn't working.

Feed me knowledge please!

[EDIT]

The answer is perfect for overriding CSS! Thanks

Note: Clear cache and browsing data from the beginning of time, it helps ;)

Comment: It might depend on when your `$('body').css()` rule takes place--does it run after the page has already loaded?

Comment: Works for me in FF, Chrome, and IE: http://jsbin.com/ubenar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to force this style to be applied in case there are conflicts then use `!important` after the style.

```
$(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', 'blue !important');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the css equals to inline style,  so isn't it stronger then every other csse rule even without the !important?

Comment: If you have `!important` applied in the css class styles then inline style will also not help. To override that we need to specify `!important` within inline styles also.

Comment: @gdoron: Sadly, a stylesheet style with `!important` is stronger than an inline style that isn't `!important`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. What is it "sadly"?

Comment: @gdoron: Sorry, matter of opinion. My view is nothing should be stronger than an inline style, or at least nothing in an author stylesheet (a user stylesheet is another matter).

Answer (score 2):

Using `!important` will push the priority of this style:

```
$('body').css('background-color', 'blue !important');
```

However it might be worth posting up more of your source code, as there is often a better solution than using `!important`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Unless `!important` has been set on a linked stylesheet somewhere. I'm pretty confident !important on a stylesheet has a higher priority than an inline style without !important

Comment: `@Curt`: Ugh. I'm sorry to say that you appear to be correct about that: http://jsbin.com/ubenar/2 (I can't immediately find that statement in the CSS spec, but when Chrome, Firefox, and IE all agree, figure I'm just missing it.) Yet another reason to avoid `!important` like the plague. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's something we can both agree on!

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute it after the page is loaded:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('body').css('background', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, maybe try this:

```
$('body').css('background', 'blue !important');
```

But you should see where the conflicting is coming from and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("body").css("background-color","blue!important");
     });

</script>
```